# Multiple email addresses for same user

Tags: linux, email, exim

I have a Linux (Debian) OS running Exim4. I own two domain names that both use the same email server and the addresses are:

me@domain1.com

me@domain2.com

Exim always delivers mail to `/storage/mail/me/Maildir`. When I set up my accounts in Outlook 2007 each account receives all the mail for both domains. Is there a way so that I can have two different accounts with the same username `me` where email for me@domain1.com goes to a different `Maildir` such as:

me@domain1.com => `/storage/mail/me/domain1.com/Maildir`

me@domain2.com => `/storage/mail/me/domain2.com/Maildir`

so that in Outlook I will receive email for domain1.com in one account and email at domain2.com in another account?

Comment: First you need to say what your LDA is, are you using virtual users or system users, and probably something else I can't think of.. BTW, yes you can, but how requires more information.

Comment: I am pretty bad with mail servers but I think I am using system users who each get a password specified in `/et/exim4/passwd`.

Comment: Do you want "mailbox only" accounts?

Comment: I am not sure on the exact meaning of your question but if you mean do I want `mbox` or `Maildir` then I am using `Maildir`.

Comment: Sure you decide only by `local_part` where message should be delivered. Because both addresses has the same `local_part` LDA always happens as `domain` part is the `domain1.com`. Can you show your routers? Also, logically much more clear to config mailstorage as `/storage/mail/domain/user`.